# How to use ( yumdownloader --resolve <package name> ) on ( yum -y groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts" )?

Tags: linux, centos, x11, yum, repository

As soon as I finish installing "centos-minimal" from the minimal ISO file, I need to install the GUI desktop. for this I simply run, `ifup eth0`, and then I run:

```
yum -y groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"
```

I would like to install all these from a local folder if possible. Here's what I know.

For example to install `gcc` locally I can simply create a folder named `gcc` on my USB stick for example. Then go into that folder and then run this command:

```
yumdownloader --resolve gcc
```

This will download everything needed to install `gcc` on my system, assuming that system does not yet have `gcc` installed. It will download all of the dependencies and so on, into the folder: `gcc`.

Then the next time around when I re-install CentOS minimal, I can just go into this folder and run:

```
yum --nogpgcheck localinstall *.rpm -y
```

It installs `gcc` as long as I'm in the "gcc" folder with all the files that were downloaded.

The question is, how to apply this to this command:

```
yum -y groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"
```

Because I don't think there is such program as:

```
 "Desktop" and so on..
```

What would the `yum install <package name> -y` equivalency be for:

```
yum -y groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"
```

because if I knew that, then I could use this:

```
yumdownloader --resolve <package name>
```

To download all the necessary packages to a folder and then install the GUI from a folder without an internet connection the next time around, when I re-installed CentOS minimal Linux.

Answer (score 1):

yum's `groupinfo` predicate will list all the required and optional packages contained in one or more groups.

```
yum groupinfo Desktop "Desktop Platform" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own yum repository from the folder which contains all the rpm you downloaded.
the major benefit is the automated dependency management.